# Navigation view that can be opened from left to right and right to left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my application, I would like to implement two navigation views, one can be opened from left to right (normal implementation) and other can be opend from right to left. This is exactly like the StackOverFlow app for Android.

Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved? I don't want to use any third party libraries for this as I hope there should be a native way of implementing it (Like StackOverFlow app)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a second drawer `View` under the first one in the `DrawerLayout`, with its `layout_gravity` set to `"right|end"`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! :)
If you put that as answer, I will mark it as solution. Thanks once again.

Comment: It's cool. No need to have the same answer here twice. That's why I voted it as a duplicate, which you already marked as helpful, so I can't post an answer anyway. Thanks, though. Cheers!